# Android VideoView fails to play multicasted stream

Tags: android, streaming, vlc, rtp

I am attempting to play a stream encoded with h264 / aac that is transmitted from VLC over multicast. I am setting up a wifi multicast lock prior to starting the video view. Using an SDP file read from the sdcard, I get these errors in LogCat upon start:

`E/ASessionDescription: ASessionDescription::getServerSessionURL: Did not get the Server URL info from the control attribute...Checking in Origin Info
E/ASessionDescription: ASessionDescription::getServerURLFromOriginAndSessionName : URL info not present in the Session name
E/ASessionDescription: ASessionDescription::getServerSessionURL: Did not get the Server URL info Origin field
E/NuPlayer: getServerSessionURL for SDP Failed`

This is the content of my sdp file:

```
v=0
o=- 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 192.168.16.1
s=Multicast stream test
c=IN IP4 239.10.1.1/127
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 5004 RTP/AVP 96 97
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
a=rtpmap:97 MPEG-4-GENERIC/44100/2
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=1;mode=AAC-hbr;sizelength=13;indexlength=3;indexltalength=3; config=1210
a=orient:portrait
```

All the devices are on the same network. This shows the simplicity of the code:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.playback_view);
videoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.sdp");
videoView.start();
```

I've also tried this VLC generated sdp with MP3 audio, it also fails to play

```
v=0
o=- 15403293578011388063 15403293578011388063 IN IP4 192.168.1.2
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 239.10.1.1/255
t=0 0
a=tool:vlc 2.0.7
a=recvonly
a=type:broadcast
a=charset:UTF-8
m=audio 5004 RTP/AVP 14
b=AS:128
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:14 MPA/90000/2
m=video 5006 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:800
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001e;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAHqzZQLQnsBEAAAMAAQAAAwAyjxYtlg==,aOvssiw=;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still not supported in Android as of version 4.4. I had to end up using JavaCV for this project.

Answer (score -1):

android rtsp. can't support mp3 codec.

see. 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/l-preview/media/libstagefright/rtsp/ARTPSource.cpp

Comment: Your answer should be more constructive. The question explains that it was trying to _"play a stream encoded with h264"_ so the _"mp3 codec"_ doesn't seem to apply.